# black screen while parsing local JSON file android

Tags: android, json, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse a Large JSON file that contains 24,000 lines(it contains regular Expressions to detect sms from sms provider) , the file is locally stored in assets folder here's the code of my class

```
public class SmsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> msg;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
JSONObject obj;
JSONArray rules_array;
JSONObject rule_object = null;
String body, address, smsDate;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    permission();

}

void permission() {
    // first check for permissions
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                10);
    } else {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Inbox());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Inbox());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is granted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {//If permission is not granted,then it will ask for permission .
                permission();
            }
        }

    }
}

public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("sms_formats.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}


//Arraylist is used to create dynamic array.The size can be varried .
public ArrayList<String> Inbox() {

    msg = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        //A Uri object is usually used to tell a ContentProvider what we want to access by reference.In this ,we are accessing inbox.
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        //ContentResolver is used to request the content.
        //cursor object gets the data.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"}, null, null, null);

        obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        if (!obj.isNull("rules")) {
            rules_array = obj.getJSONArray("rules");

            //It checks whether there is any messages in inbox.If there is no message then the following if statement will not be executed.
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


                    address = cursor.getString(1);
                    body = cursor.getString(3);

                    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
                    Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
                    smsDate = finaldate.toString();


                    for (int i = 0; i < rules_array.length(); i++) {

                        rule_object = rules_array.getJSONObject(i);


                        if (!rule_object.isNull("name")) {
                            // you have a name for the rule
                            Log.e("NO", "error");
                        }
                        if (!rule_object.isNull("patterns")) {
                            JSONArray pattern_array = rule_object.getJSONArray("patterns");
                            for (int j = 0; j < pattern_array.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject pattern_obj = pattern_array.getJSONObject(j);
                                if (!pattern_obj.isNull("regex")) {

                                    String type = pattern_obj.getString("sms_type");

                                    if (type.equals("transaction")) {
                                        String regex = pattern_obj.getString("regex");
                                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
                                        if (matcher.find()) {
                                            msg.add("\nSender=>" + address + "\n" + "Message=>" + body + "\n" + "Date and Time=>" + smsDate + "\n");

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return msg;
}
```

}

The problem here is when i use Android studio debugger i can see that all JSON objects and JSONArrays have the values they are supposed to have.But when i run the app on the phone it gives me black screen with no output.
I tried to implement AsyncTask cause I thought the black screen was due the large amount of data it was processing on the main thread from the JSON file, but it didn't help either. Can Someone please point me in the right direction.

Ps-I'm a beginner in Android Development

edit added AsyncTask.

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    String bodyData;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... body) {

        bodyData = body.toString();
        if (!obj.isNull("rules")) {
            try {
                rules_array = obj.getJSONArray("rules");


                for (int i = 0; i < rules_array.length(); i++) {
                    rule_object = rules_array.getJSONObject(i);


                    if (!rule_object.isNull("name")) {
                        // you have a name for the rule
                        Log.e("NO", "error");
                    }
                    if (!rule_object.isNull("patterns")) {
                        JSONArray pattern_array = rule_object.getJSONArray("patterns");
                        for (int j = 0; j < pattern_array.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject pattern_obj = pattern_array.getJSONObject(j);
                            if (!pattern_obj.isNull("regex")) {
                                return pattern_obj;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject pattern_obj) {
        super.onPostExecute(pattern_obj);
        String type = null;
        try {
            type = pattern_obj.getString("sms_type");

            if (type.equals("transaction")) {
                String regex = pattern_obj.getString("regex");
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bodyData);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    msg.add("\nSender=>" + address + "\n" + "Message=>" + body + "\n" + "Date and Time=>" + smsDate + "\n");
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: accept answers to the question that have helped you solve your problem. Its a little reward for people who waste time on them

Comment: Yes sir! i Surely do that. :)

Comment: How do you implement AsyncTask? Can you share us that ?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: And how you execute it in Activity? Thanks

Comment: The first block of code you see is latest version, the block with asynctask is prev version , that's the reason you can't see my execution :p. I executed it in inbox() method

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a large JSON file that contains 24,000 lines is complex work. Using `AsynTask` to perform that stuff in `worker thread`, then publish result in `UI thread`

> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction, this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog. The user might then decide to quit your application and uninstall it if they are unhappy.

This stuff below could be done in `worker thread`, so you don't have to put it into `onPostExecute()` which runs on UI thread (That's the reason your UI had been blocking)

```
String type = null;
try {
    type = pattern_obj.getString("sms_type");

    if (type.equals("transaction")) {
        String regex = pattern_obj.getString("regex");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bodyData);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            msg.add("\nSender=>" + address + "\n" + "Message=>" + body + "\n" + "Date and Time=>" + smsDate + "\n");
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So it could be something like this

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... body) {
        // do your complex work
        // This run on Worker Thread
        return aJsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        // Doing anything with your view
        // This run on UI Thread
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks now i can see my activity but the data is never displayed (i'm setting the adapter in onPostExecute()) . May be cause it's still processing in the background (waited for like 3 min but it never finished ), is there a way i could display 10 items in the list and while the user scrolls, load the remaining items simultaneously.

Comment: Hey, can you upload your code to github or anywhere, so I can take a look